# help integrating complex line integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How do i integrate $\int_c(z^2+1)^2dz$ along the arc of the cycloid $x=a(\theta-sin\theta),y=a(1-cos\theta)$ from the point where $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$.
I have tried putting the values by breaking z =x+iy, but it turned out to be too cumbersome. Can anyone offer a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is more the [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral), i.e. integrating over the curve, rather than just integrating from one boundary to another, right?

You would solve this with help of the formula

$\int_C ds f(x) = \int_a^b dt f(x(t))\ |x'(t)|$

In your case $x(t)$ is the cycloid $x(\theta)= a((\theta-sin(\theta))+i(1-cos(\theta)))$

You also want to express your complex number $z$ in its polar representation as $z=r\ e^{i\theta}$. Remember $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. Instead of the cartesian representation $\Re(z)\hat{e}_x + \Im(z) i\hat{e}_y$ you now choose the radius $r$ and the angle $\theta$ to represent your number in the complex plane.

This gives you the integral
$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \ (r²e^{2i\theta}+1)^2 x'(\theta)$

EDIT: Kevin is of course right, that the integral will be zero over the closed curve without singularities in the function to integrate. I just thought the problem is meant to be more general about line integrals.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what "r" is?

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma$ be the cycloid, since $\gamma(0)=\gamma(2π)=0$ and $(z^2+1)^2$ is analytic over the closed curve the line integral equals $0$.